# Update multiple table column values using single query in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables like Temp1 and Temp2

The Table Temp1 have id and Col1 fields and 
The Table Temp2 have id and Col2 fields

I need to update the two table fields Col1 and Col2 using single query in SQL.

Can anyone help me??????

Comment: You'll need to elaborate slightly. What are you trying to update the tables with? The same data? Data to be referenced between the tables?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in single query? Homework assignemnt?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that using a single query

Comment: The most important thing to specify is which database, some allow it some don't. I think these are extensions to the standard. (from top of my head: mysql supports it, oracle and postgres too i believe, ms sql don't)

Answer (score 0):

You can't update 2 tables in single SQL.
Use stored procedure or transaction

Comment: ok riho....!

thanks for your reply.

ok..... i need Stored procedure or transaction..
please give some examples...

Comment: Read the manuals for your database system. It is different in MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL,Firebird, etc.